# Get PhpStorm to understand advanced SQL built in php code

Tags: php, sql, validation, phpstorm, heredoc

```
function getCities($countryId = NULL) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM city";
   if ($countryId) {
       $sql .= <<<SQL
       WHERE countryId=$countryId
SQL;
   }
   $db->query($sql)
   ....
}
```

I often write code like the function above. I use PhpStorm and have connected it to my database so it gives me code assistance on the $sql, but only on the first part. By using HEREDOC on the part in the if-statement it will colour the SQL correctly, but I am unable to get any code assistance. Is that possible in any way? Or is there other ways I can build the SQL in php code so that PhpStorm will give me assistance?

Comment: sometimes I have a separate sql file in place and write the code in the SQL file so that PHPStorm doesn't get confused flipping in and out of any transitional languages (such as PHP) and then once it's done I just copy and paste into the PHP code. This would only really work if you're building block statements rather than ones that are dynamic....

Comment: I don't think there's a way, but maybe you could submit a suggestion at youtrack.jetbrains.com. It seems like a pretty difficult problem, expecting it to figure out that this code fragment is a continuation of the SQL query started earlier, so that it knows which table to search for column names.

Comment: i wouldn't call that advanced, but rather overly complicated and prone to SQL-Injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some assistance in Heredoc SQL in PHPStorm, at least in v2019.

I have autocomplete and suggestions, and the tables and column names and also the SQL syntax is validated.
For that, I had to to the following:

1. **Connect to the database** in use IN PHPStorm in the Database tool window (View | Tool Windows | Database)
   Detailed instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-data-sources.html
2. **Configure the SQL dialect** in user under File | Settings | Languages and Frameworks | SQL Dialects
   Details here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-languages-sql-dialects.html

Extra cool: the table names and column names are linked.